# PHP: how to pass an Array to object's member function?

Tags: php, arrays, object

is there a way to pass an array to a member function?
i tried this code:

```
class Testing
{
   public function set($arr)
   { 
      echo $arr['key'];
   }
}
```

but i got this error:  *Undefined index (key)*

Comment: is  $arr['key'] defined?

Comment: Where are you calling the `set` method from ? if you pass it an array that has the a key of `key` then it will work ..... maybe I misread the question ?

Comment: Does the array you passed has the index `key`?

Comment: you all were right, the problem was- no index `key`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass an array, just like how you have done.

The problem is, the array you passed does not have a member with the a key of `key`.

You can enforce passing an array by placing a preceding `Array` before the argument in the argument signature.

```
public function set(Array $arr) { ... }
```

You can also check for an array key being set with `isset()` or `array_key_exists()`, the latter which works with keys with the `NULL` value.

Answer (score 1):

You pass an array to a method, like you pass any other type to a method

```
$o = new Testing;
$array = array('key' => 'Hello World');
$o->set($array);
```

In your case it seems, that your array is just invalid (=> it doesn't have a key named "key").